# What are supported types for keys of hash in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

Can we use any type for keys of hash in Freemarker ?

For instance:

In Java we have:
`Hash<User, Boolean> mapUserToSelected = new HashMap<>()`

And in Freemarker we have:

```
<#list mapUserToSelected as user, selected>
  <p>${user.name}</p>
  <p>${selected?c}</p>
</#list>
```

However, we got **"The following has evaluated to null or missing"** for the `<p>${selected?c}</p>` and I am sure that it exists in the map.

If I use String for keys of hash `Hash<String, Boolean> mapUserToSelected = new HashMap<>()` it will work.

Is the key of hash needed to be **String** only?

Comment: You have a tipo in your Freemarker template.

Comment: What is the full class name of Hash? Or is it an another tipo?

Comment: It is a classic HashMap

Comment: Would you correct your Java line accordingly then? Did you notice that my other comment probably solved your problem?

Comment: No, it is not about the typo, it does not answer my question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the builtin `?c` works for Boolean too? Could you try `<p>${selected}</p>`?

Comment: I do not think the map is a problem, otherwise the ${user.name} would not work either.

Answer (score 0):

The object `mapUserToSelected` can contain any `Object` as key, the built in ?c will [convert a string to numeric](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_c). Not sure why you're applying it to Boolean.

Also, not to confuse ourselves: When we want to send the object `mapUserToSelected` from Logic (controller) to UI then tha's when the key must be String based on the definition of `TemplateHashModel`.
Example:

```
ModelAndView mainView = new ModelAndView();
mainView.getModel().put("usersMap", mapUserToSelected );
```

But the object itself can contain anything, you can get the keys list using `mapUserToSelected?keys` then access each the list of the keys using `?index` if you are interested in the value of every key.

Comment: [c (when used with boolean) converts a boolean to string](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html)

Yes, with `mapUserToSelected?keys` I have all `users` object, but I can not retrieve the value associated with that object in the hash.

If I change my hash to `Map<String, Boolean>`, it will work.